# Identify which QPixmapItem has been selected

Tags: c++, qt

I am adding QGraphicsPixmapItems to my scene, and I can see that when I pick on the item, it gets the white dashed selection rectangle, but I'm struggling to get any data from this selection.  Here is how I'm adding it to the scene.

```
void MainWindow::drawImage(curTarget *newTarget){
  QGraphicsPixmapItem *tgt = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;//new pixmap
  tgt = scene->addPixmap(newTarget->myIcon);//assign pixmap image
  tgt->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
  scene->addItem(tgt);
```

}

Each PixmapItem that I add to the scene has struct data associated with it, and I need to be able to retrieve that data when I select on the QGraphicsPixmapItem inside of the QGraphicsScene. If the selection rectangle is showing up when the pixmapitem is selected, isn't there some easy way to return information to me based on that fact? A Pointer to what is selected perhaps?

I do have a mousePressEvent method implemented but I'm struggling getting anything relevant with that.

```
void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
qDebug() << "Clicked" << endl;
}
```

When I run the app, I see Clicked everywhere in my scene except when I click on my pixmapitems.

I've tried every version of the mousePressEvents available and the ones that actually do something, only do something as long as I don't press on my pixmapitems.

Comment: QGraphicsScene::selectedItems() ?

Comment: `mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneEvent * event){
qDebug() << scene->selectedItems();
}`

returns nothing

Comment: Instead of overriding `mousePressEvent` create a function that checks the current selection and connect it to the [`QGraphicsScene::selectionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#selectionChanged) signal.

Comment: I understand the logic here, but unsure of the implementation.|

I'm currently struggling to get past a conversion error extending off of QGraphicsPixmapItem so that I can do a connect with signals and slots but that is going no where.

`whatIsSelected(){ qDebug << scene.selectedItems();}`

and then in my function where I add the items, I would add:

`QObject::connect(tgt, SIGNAL(whatIsSelected()), scene, SLOT(selectionChanged());`

Does that sound right?

Comment: Looks like you've got your signal and slot a bit back to front.  Should be `QObject::connect(scene, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), tgt, SLOT(whatIsSelected()))`.

Comment: Yes that worked thank you.  For some reason however, it outputs the same line 4 times...

`QGraphicsItems(0x098f4989, pos = 229, 167, flags=ItemIsSelecteable`

....when I select on something new. Is this something I should be concerned about, or normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the help I received in my comments, I will post up what ultimately worked for me.

```
      void MainWindow::drawImage(curTarget *newTarget)
    {
      QGraphicsPixmapItem *tgt = new QGraphicsPixmapItem
      tgt = scene->addPixmap(newTarget->myIcon);
      tgt->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);
      scene->addItem(tgt);
    }
```

With the new function added...

```
void MainWindow::whatIsSelected(){
QDebug() <<scene->selectedItems() << endl;}
```

And then I made the connection of the scene to the window elsewhere...

```
QObject::connect(scene, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(whatIsSelected);
```

Comment: This is OK if you only call drawImage once, but each time you call "connect", it creates a new connection without removing the old one. If you add a lot of images, the "whatIsSelected" method will start getting called many times each time the selection changes. Either move the "connect" call elsewhere so that it's only done once, or add the Qt::UniqueConnection connection type to the "connect" call.

Comment: I definitely need it added on each item I create. My users will require the ability to select/deselect as often as they want in order to explore the data associated. And there will be a great amount of images being added.

Comment: Not sure I was clear. The signal/slot connection needs to only be done once, and it can be done any time after both the MainWindow and the scene have been created. Using the UniqueConnection prevents multiple connections from being created, but you do not need to call "connect" every time. I should've said that it's preferable to move the "connect" call elsewhere, probably either into the MainWindow constructor or wherever "scene" is created. The above version works, but the call to "connect" every time an image is added is not necessary.

Comment: Yes, I did ultimately move it elsewhere, and that was a better choice, thank you.