# Changing Pixmap assigned to non-selected QGraphicsItems

Tags: c++, qt

In my QGraphicsScene, I am adding several pointers. See initial thread [Identify which QPixmapItem has been selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40469417/identify-which-qpixmapitem-has-been-selected/40473052?noredirect=1#comment68192273_40473052)

These pointers have QPixmaps assigned to them. When I select on these pointers, I can get all of the information I have associated with them, except the ability to change the pixmap assigned to it when the pointer is NOT selected.

basically, I can change the pixmap when its selected because that state is easy to pull from, but I'm not sure how to reset the other items back to their original image when they are no longer selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the simple solution would have been to use the QgraphicsScene SIGNAL focusItemChanged(), but for whatever reason, it simply would not emit.

However, I was able to add a new list to grab all of the items in the scene, set their values to the "off state" image, and then run through and assign the "on state" image only to the one selected.

```
void MainWindow::whatIsSelected()
{
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> allItems_list = scene->items();
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> selItem_list = scene->selectedItems();

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, allItems_list)
    {
         //assign off state images
    }

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item, selItem_list)
    {
         //assign on state image
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to enable the [`QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemFlag-enum) flag for your items, if you want your scene to emit `focusItemChanged` signal. However, if all you want to do is change the image when an item is selected, then it would be better to create a class that inherits from `QGrapihcsItem` and draw a specific pixmap based on what [`isSelected`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#isSelected) returns.